# Fluent builder design pattern - how to force customer to set variables

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder

I have a problem with design pattern. Let's say i have a simple class:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private int age;

    private Person(){}

    public String toString()
    {
        return "name: "+name+" surname: "+surname+" age: "+age;
    }

    public static final class Builder{

        private String name;
        private String surname;
        private int age;

        public Builder name (String name){
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder surname (String surname){
            this.surname = surname;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder age (int age){
            this.age = age;
            return this;
        }

        public Person build(){
            Person person = new Person();
            person.name=name;
            person.surname=surname;
            person.age=age;
            return person;
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine, but it's not required to set variables before invoking "build" method. How could i change that?

Comment: You can use a lambda based builder to force a sequence of method calls before the user can call `build()`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, there are so many different versions of the Builder pattern. Would you mind linking to the one you're referring to?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to enforce that would be to throw an exception in `build()` if not everythig was set. Along with documentation this might be enough already but it wouldn't provide any compiletime checks.

An alternative, if you're ok with also enforcing some order, could be the use of "step" objects:

```
class Builder {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private int age;

    //start with the name and create a new builder
    public static SurnameStep name(String name) {
        Builder builder = new Builder();
        builder.name = name;
    
        return builder.new SurnameStep();       
    }

    public class SurnameStep {
        public AgeStep surname(String surname) {
            Builder.this.surname = surname;
            return new AgeStep();
        }
    }

    public class AgeStep {
        public Builder age(int age) {
            Builder.this.age = age;
            return Builder.this;
        }
    }

    public Person build() {
        //build person here
    }
}
```

Usage would then need to be like this:

```
Person p = Builder.name("John").surname("Smith").age(42).build();
```

Name, surname and age would all need to be specified and in that order before `build()` would even be available.

If all fields are mandatory you could also get rid of `build()` and create the `Person` already in `age(int)`.

Also note that instead of putting the steps into `Builder` you could put them directly into `Person`. The static "init" method `name(String)` would already create a `Person` instance but it would only become accessible after the call to `age(int)`:

```
//expanded to make it more obvious: the steps don't provide access to the Person until all have been executed
SurnameStep surnameStep = Person.name("John");
AgeStep ageStep = surnameStep .surname("Smith");
Person johnSmith = ageStep.age(42);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can improve this code by doing few things:

1. Create non-default constructor of Person which accepts all 3 values

```java
public class Person {
    public Person(String first, String last, int age) {
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

2. Add validation of arguments in this constructor throwing IllegalArgumentException

```java
if (age < 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Age cannot be negative: " + age);
}
if (first == null && last == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("first or last name is null");
}
```

3. (Optional, for use in unit tests) you can also initialize default values in Builder for test purposes in a static factory method and non-default constructor:

```java
public static Builder someAdultPerson() {
    return new Builder("Erika", "Mustermann", 18);
}
```

4. Support BDD notation in your tests with this interface:

```java
interface Builder<T> {
    T build();
    static <C> given(Builder<C> builder) { return builder.build(); }
}
... 
class Person {
    class Builder implements my.example.Builder<Person> { ... }
}
...
import static Person.Builder.someAdultPerson;
...
Person person = given(someAdultPerson().age(27));
```